# Angularjs why does array not update on front end?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, service, dependency-injection

I have two controllers, CompositionsController and CritiqueController and they use a service called Critiques to share an array object. I want to display the updated array object on the front-end. I console.err out the innerds of the array and you see that it updates, but does not update on the front-end. What am I doing wrong?

Also, side note, is it appropriate to have services that fulfill one function, to ensure that an array of critques are shared?

```
myApp.factory('Critiques', function () {
  return new Array();
});
```

Here is test of my application:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3Wu7UH?p=preview

Also, to test my application, you must click the Capitalization button and then on a span tag. , which will add a model object called 'critique' into my array of 'critiques'.

Thank you for any kind of help or suggestions I should make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$scope.critiques` is modified in a jQuery's event handler, hence angular will not aware if it's changed.

You have to manually run `$scope.$apply()` afterward, to see it reflect on views.

And after the `$scope.$apply()` is added, you will found an another error says:

```
Error: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: critique in critiques
```

That is because the same `$scope.critique` object is added to `$scope.critiques` everytime you click the spans. The `ng-repeat` doesn't allow any duplicate objects.

You could workaround that by using `angular.copy()` like this:

```
$scope.critiques.push(angular.copy($scope.critique));
```

or you might want to change how the `critique` object is construct.

**Here is a working example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/GjW4cN?p=preview

Comment: Thank you,this works. Except, I don't know if I want to do a 'workaround'... I researched further into angular directives and I came up with another solution. Would you mind taking a look at this plnkr? http://plnkr.co/edit/3Wu7UH?p=preview

Comment: That is the same plunker. Did you forget to freeze it in order to make changes become public?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {

      $scope.apply();
}
```

Problem might be that the view has already been written by the time you update the array.